# KeyListener on function keys

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I want to listen on F3 key pressed inside my JFrame.
How is this possible?

Something like this:

```
this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == F3)
            MyFrame.this.dispose();
    }
});
```

Comment: Have a look at all those juicy constants in `KeyEvent`, especially `VK_F3` :)

Comment: Thank you. That is what I searched for.

Comment: For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`.

Comment: I can't use key bindings as they don't exist in my Java 8. My JComponent classes have no getInputMap or getActionMap functions.

Comment: Those methods have existed since JDK1.3.

Comment: If I want to do ```this.getInputMap()``` in my JFrame, this is impossible, as those method doesn't even exist.

Comment: What I want to do is: no matter which component has Focus, when F3 pressed dispose the Frame.

Answer (score 1):

Using solution from Benson99 as a springboard, I think the following should work.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class KeyListenFrame extends JFrame {

    public KeyListenFrame() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Key Listener Frame - Press F3 to close frame");
        frame.setSize(600, 300);

        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F3) {
                    System.out.println("Pressed " + e.getKeyCode());
                    System.out.println("Closing frame");
                    frame.dispose();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Pressed " + e.getKeyCode());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            }
        });
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyListenFrame keyListenFrame = new KeyListenFrame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use keyPressed for the function keys.  Try this code and press keys.  Function keys won't fire a key typed event.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(200,200);

    frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("from keyTyped: " + e.getKeyCode());
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {                
            System.out.println("from keyPressed: " + e.getKeyCode());
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    });
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I added the KeyListener directly to the JFrame, but it is never called...

Comment: For all keys, or just no call for the function key press?

Comment: For all keys never called, no matter which component has focus.

Comment: *I added the KeyListener directly to the JFrame, but it is never called...* - which is why you should be using `Key Bindings` as Andrew suggested earlier. It allows you to handle KeyStrokes even when a component doesn't have focus.

Comment: I'd have to see more of your code to figure out why your key listener isn't registering. If you tried that main() function I posted (in a new project) and it isn't working, you may have an operating system issue.

Comment: @Benson99, KeyEvents are only dispatched to the component with focus. The frame won't have focus when other components are added. Read the link provided by Andrew in the comments section for the question. All Swing components use "Key Bindings". You can also check out: [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for more information.

Comment: How do I do this independend from the Focus?

Comment: That's a good question that I don't have the answer for. I tried some key bindings, hoping to find a way to allow the event to "bubble" up and be captured at the top-most component (frame.getRootPane()) and I couldn't get it to work.  Good luck, Phil. My solution about 6 years back was to ditch swing and go to JavaFX :)

Answer (score 0):

> If I want to do this.getInputMap() in my JFrame, this is impossible

Because a JFrame is NOT a JComponent.

You add Key Bindings to a JComponent. In this case you would add the Key Bindings to the "root pane" of the JFrame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html#rootpane) for basic information.

I also showed you how to access the root pane in the link I provide above on [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/).